# Angular : Factory and object creation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

Basic example of what i want to build :

I want a class "Fire" with attributes : "power" and "position".

I want a "Manager" who can have access to a list of Fire. I also need to share the "Fire" model to others class so i think i need to build a factory.

First shot, i did this :

```
// FACTORY
simuApp.factory('FireFactory', function() {

    return {
        list_fire: [],

        createFire: function(p_power) {
            return {
                id : null,
                power : p_power,
                position : {
                    x: null,
                    y: null
                }
            }
        }
    }

});
```

But i feel there's something wrong.

I cannot hold the list of fires and have a method to create a fire.

I'm totally lost, can you help me to understand a good implementation ?

Comment: Your factory does not return anything.

Comment: My bad when I copy the code, it's wrapped in a return of course. I can't edit the answer at the moment.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I don't see any return within the factory.Anyway posted an answer that might help you out.